# Very slow Wi-Fi with Intel 3165 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I have a Dell Inspiron 7559 with an Intel Wireless 3165-AC. I recently did a clean install of 16.04, replacing my old 14.04 installation, and have since been having trouble with my wireless card. The speed is usually very slow around 200-400 KB/s, and at times even drops to less than 100. In comparison, I used to get > 1 MB/s on 14.04 on the same network.

I tried upgrading to the latest firmware files (1.162), tried putting newer iwlwifi files in /lib/firmware, turned off power management, but nothing seems to help. Looking for some suggestions as to what could be wrong and what's the best way to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

I own and use successfully two Intel wireless devices. I have honed a few techniques in several years and thousands of forum posts.

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi 11n_disable=8
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Finally, Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available. Please make your tests with the ethernet detached.